# Turn a table of JSON paths and values into a JSON object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, for-json

I've got a table in my database that contains a bunch of JSON paths and the values at those paths. I want to take the data in that table and construct a JSON object out of it. I'm more of a .NET guy and my go to approach with that kind of background would just be to run a WHILE loop and call `JSON_MODIFY()` for each row in the table, but I'm posting here in hopes that someone has a more elegant/efficient solution that'd be more appropriate for SQL. It seems like `OPENJSON()` might be able to help me out here, but I'm not quite sure how to use it to here.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JsonData]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [Path] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Value] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)
```

Not sure if the empty object value with Id #1 and #6 are necessary for all solutions to this. But with the WHILE loop at least it ensured we got the base object created so that `JSON_MODIFY()` could set the properties on it.

**Sample Data**

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[JsonData] ([Path], [Value])
VALUES
('FullName', '{}'),
('FullName.FirstName', 'Robert'),
('FullName.MiddleName', 'John'),
('FullName.LastName', 'Downey'),
('FullName.Suffix', 'Jr.'),
('CurrentDate', '{}'),
('CurrentDate.Month', 'February'),
('CurrentDate.Day', '22'),
('CurrentDate.Year', '2024')
```

**Desired Outcome**

```
{
  "FullName": {
    "FirstName": "Robert",
    "MiddleName": "John",
    "LastName": "Downey",
    "Suffix": "Jr."
  },
  "CurrentDate": {
    "Month": "February",
    "Day": 22,
    "Year": 2024
  }
}
```

I appreciate any advice!

**My Rudimentary WHILE loop solution**

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX) = '{}'
DECLARE @currentId INT
DECLARE @finalId INT

SELECT
    @currentId = MIN(Id),
    @finalId = MAX(Id)
FROM
    JsonData

WHILE @currentId <= @finalId
BEGIN
    DECLARE @path VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @value VARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT
        @path = j.[Path],
        @value = j.[Value]
    FROM
        JsonData j
    WHERE
        j.Id = @currentId

    DECLARE @fullPath varchar(max) = FORMATMESSAGE('$.%s', @path)
    IF ISJSON(@value) = 1 -- Not ideal, but took a hacky route here to make this work as an example
        SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, @fullPath, JSON_QUERY(@value))
    ELSE IF TRY_CONVERT(INT, @value) IS NOT NULL
        SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, @fullPath, CAST(@value as INT))
    ELSE
        SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, @fullPath, @value)

    SET @currentId = @currentId + 1
END
```

**SQL Version**
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Dec  6 2023 08:32:07   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation

To clarify, here's the complete business requirements

1. Should be able to handle any valid JSON path (i.e. anything that could be passed into `JSON_MODIFY`). We have flexibility on how to format the incoming paths if that is helpful somehow
2. Should handle duplicate paths in the table and insert the latest data (higher ID = newer data) into the final JSON object
3. Data should be inserted into the JSON object in its 'native' form. I'm sure there's a better way to phrase this, but as an example I mean that if '12' is in the `Value` column, it should go into the JSON as 12 and not '12'. We can add a column for data type to the JsonData table and populate it with the correct data type if that's helpful. I edited in a rudimentary way to do this in my example SQL although I expect that wouldn't be the best long term solution
4. Should be able to handle a decent amount of data. In our use case, I think we're expecting this table to have between 100 and 500 rows of applicable data, with the usual number being ~200. I think this might rule out the recursive approach

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You can use a recursive CTE to do the json_modify thing, as long as it's not too many rows it should work fine

Comment: @DaleK - Sorry, I didn't mean to be condescending. I didn't initially include my attempt because I didn't want to make the post overwhelmingly long and my hope was that the blurb at the top sufficiently explained how I originally approached this. I went ahead and pasted in something similar to the code I had been working on

Comment: I suppose that's fair, but I was trying to make it optional because I thought it was something I could figure out on my own if needed once I had a starting point. Just trying to make it easier on the kind folks who try to help out

Comment: @Everix so now that you have 2 answers, did either of them help you?

Comment: 500 rows of data is nothing... millions of rows, then you might have to worry about performance.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option using Dynamic SQL

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = (
Select 'Select '+string_agg(quotename(Path)+'='''+string_escape(value,'json')+'''',',') + ' For JSON Path, Without_Array_Wrapper '
 From #YourTable
 Where Value<>'{}' 
)

Exec(@SQL)
```

**Results**

```
{
    "FullName": {
        "FirstName": "Robert",
        "MiddleName": "John",
        "LastName": "Downey",
        "Suffix": "Jr."
    },
    "CurrentDate": {
        "Month": "February",
        "Day": "22",
        "Year": "2024"
    }
}
```

Update.  Just noticed the Latest Path requirement

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = (
Select 'Select '+string_agg(quotename(Path)+'='''+string_escape(value,'json')+'''',',') + ' For JSON Path, Without_Array_Wrapper '
 From (Select top 1 with ties *
        From YourTable
        Order By row_number() over (partition by path order by id desc)
      ) A
 Where Value<>'{}' 
)
Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: Very nice, altough it wouldn't work with multiple "records" I guess

Comment: @siggemannen Agreed.  Assuming an EAV structure, OP didn't present an Entity value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following recursive CTE.

- Start with an empty object, and an Id lower than the lowest possible.
- Recurse the CTE and `OUTER APPLY` the following:

  - Look for all rows in the table greater than the current ID.
  - Assign a row-number, and filter that to 1 to get the first row.
  - You'll be pleased to know the compiler turns this into a `TOP (1)` automatically.
    We can't do this as it's not allowed in a rCTE.
- Check the original ID is not null, otherwise we'll recurse forever.
- Select out of the CTE, filtering only to the one possible row that has a null ID: the last one.
- We can use `ISJSON` to check for those `{}` values. They aren't strictly necessary if you have child properties of those, but you may need them if you don't have those.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CAST(N'{}' AS nvarchar(max)) AS json, 0 AS Id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      IIF(jd.Path IS NULL,
        cte.json,
        IIF(ISJSON(jd.Value) = 1,
          JSON_MODIFY(cte.json, '$.' + jd.Path, JSON_QUERY(jd.value)),
          JSON_MODIFY(cte.json, '$.' + jd.Path, jd.Value)
        )
      ),
      jd.Id
    FROM cte
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY jd.Id) AS rn
            FROM JsonData jd
            WHERE jd.Id > cte.Id
        ) jd
        WHERE jd.rn = 1
    ) jd
    WHERE cte.Id IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT cte.json
FROM cte
WHERE cte.Id IS NULL;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/rQ2vyq3D)